# how to create working Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I create a child theme, but then I want to add some style it not change in my main menu.

I create a folder aloshop-child in the direction

```
\public_html\wp-content\themes
```

In this folder I create two files style.css and function.php
In function.php I added code:

```
<?php

function aloshop_child_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'aloshop';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'aloshop',
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
array( $parent_style )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aloshop_child_enqueue_styles' );
```

and in style.css add just simple information

```
/*
Theme Name: Aloshop child theme
Author: Mantas Slau
Description: A child theme of the Aloshop default WordPress theme
Version: 1.1
Template:     aloshop
*/
```

Next what I did, in the dashboard activated this child theme.

So I tried to check if this child theme works. I cut from my visual composer custom css code (which I was temporary added then I developed my page) and paste it in the child theme --> `style.css.

```
 /*
    Theme Name: Aloshop child theme
    Author: Mantas Slau
    Description: A child theme of the Aloshop default WordPress theme
    Version: 1.1
    Template:     aloshop
    */

    .footer-box  h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin: 0 0 13px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fe9c00;
    }
    .menu-footer a {
        border-left: 1px solid #dadada;
        display: block;
        height: 14px;
        line-height: 14px;
        padding: 0 13px;
        color: white;
    }
    .footer-box  p {
       color: white;
    }
    .footer-menu-box-end a {
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .footer-menu-box-end a:hover{
        color: #fe9c00;
    }
    .footer-menu-box-end  h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin: 0 0 13px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #fe9c00;
    }
    .footer-box-contact  a {
       color: white;
    }
    .social-footer li:first-child a{
        margin-left:10;
    }
    .social-footer.social-network label {
        margin: 0 0 10px;
        color: #fe9c00;
    }
    .category-home-label span {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .sub-menu-top {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .list-child-category {
        min-height: 155px;
    }
    .woocommerce div.product .product_title {
      font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin: 0 0 13px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .price span {
      font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin: 0 0 13px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      color: #fe9c00;
    }
    .woocommerce div.product div.images img {
        /* display: block; */
        /* width: 100%; */
        /* height: auto; */
        /* box-shadow: none; */
        width: 350px;
        padding: 1px;
        border: 1px solid #e0e0d1;
        background-color: #e0e0d1;
    }
```

Style code but it doesn't make sense.

Save ---> refresh and style not working.
Can somebody help with this issue? What do I do wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function.php file,

Instead of "aloshop"

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'aloshop',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',array( $parent_style ));
```

use "aloshop-child" to call style.css file.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'aloshop-child',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',array( $parent_style ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution.  My browser creates cookies. So before the refresh needs press ctrl+f5 and it will clear the browser. My code is good.